# foreach loop throws ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, razor

I am writing an APS.NET MVC 5 application. I am stuck with small issue that I am not actually able to figure out.

I am getting error as follows:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name:
>   index'

I am fetching data from db and passing to view with different set of data.

```
    List<MasterEntity> ListOfmasterEntity = new List<MasterEntity>();
    ListOfmasterEntity.Add(masterEntityA);
    ListOfmasterEntity.Add(masterEntityB);

    return View(ListOfmasterEntity)
```

I have instantiated my master like below. MasterEntity is super class that contains List where T is various entities

```
public class PageEntity
{
        public PageEntity()
        {

        }

        public string DesignId { get; set; }
        public string DesignName { get; set; }
        public string DesignStatus { get; set; }
}
```

Master Class

```
public MasterEntity()
{
    this.ListOfPageEntity = new List<PageEntity>();
    this.ListOfuserEntity = new List<UserEntity>();
}


public List<UserEntity> ListOfuserEntity { get; set; }
public List<PageEntity> ListOfPageEntity { get; set; }
```

On the view page when I do `LINQ` my code breaks as followes.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.First().ListOfPageEntity)
{
   //This brings data for n times then 1 more lookup in collection is breaking the code. I don't exactly know why!
}
```

Comment: Where do you get this exception?

Comment: @HimBromBeere At cshtml

Comment: What is your defined Model? Also what do you mean "1 more lookup?"

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). From your shown code it´s impossible to guess what goes on.

Comment: @ZivWeissman, Model definition is update partially in question I am passing List<MasterEntity> to view and IEnumerator<MasterEntity> is binding it to view. Also, I more lookup mean, foreach is looking into collection after I get all the values that satisfy the LINQ case e.g. Currently I am getting 3 object of ListOfPageEntity thus foreach iterates over for three times, that is OK. but after this it should yield, at this point code breaks.

Comment: Please show the code inside the `foreach`

Comment: @CodingYoshi, there is single anchor in it like <a href="/Controller/Action/1/@item.MenuId/@item.ContentId">@item.MenuName</a>

Comment: Then the error is not within the foreach. The error is somewhere else.

Comment: It's the first time I ever hear of such exception in a foreach loop. Are you sure it is not happening somewhere else, or that ListPageOfEntity is not simultaneously accessed and modified by multiple threads in some way?

Comment: @MBakardzhiev, actually yes, ListPageOfEntity is used by other threads too

Comment: @Anas Still MasterEntity isn't static or singleton class, so it is indeed very strange. If it was, I would have assumed the reason is that some other threads modifies the only instance of the list.

Comment: @MBakardzhiev, I have check the scope by passing single object of master thus it shall not be modified by others but issue persists. But I am taking a note on your point. appreciate it.

Comment: OK, so this foreach - var item in Model.First().ListOfPageEntity will bring you the first 3 items of ListOfPageEntities, and what comes after that in the view?

Comment: Please include the `StackTrace` of the exception in your question.

Comment: @ZivWeissman, No item is there that I believe it should yield but page break at this point only. mjwills, I will detail stack next day it's very late here.

Comment: Please include all of your CSHTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. So finally I got the answer after spending quite some hours in debugging. Like it happen in coding time it turn out a silly.

**Short answer :** I din't handled null on cshtml where I cast it into array.

**Description :**
From my controller I am passing MasterObject to view. MasterObject is blue print of various other collections objects. There are some dynamic values are populating in MasterObject. While rendering the razor view I called the property to render it but actully it was never initialzed since there was no table returned for it. So, I needed to handle null explicitly. Finally, got it done.